# Checking if an instance *doesn't* exist -> "Not a valid member"

Tags: lua, roblox

"checkin is not a valid member of PlayerGui" at line 2

```
function onClick(plr)
    if game.Players[plr.Name].PlayerGui.checkin ~= nil then
        print('player already has gui')
    else
        if game.ServerStorage.Players[plr.Name].Value == 0 then
            local gui = game.ServerStorage.GUIs.checkin:Clone()
            gui.Parent = plr.PlayerGui
            print('fresh gui being handed to '.. plr.Name)
        end
    end
end
script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(onClick)
```

Comment: So what’s the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a member doesn't exist on an instance, Roblox will immediately throw an error.

If you're not sure if a child of a given name exists, use `:FindFirstChild(name)`. Rather than throw an error, it just returns `nil`.

---

Note that `MouseClick` already gives a player, so doing `game.Players[plr.Name]` is really redundant.

```
if plr.PlayerGui:FindFirstChild("checkin") then
```

---

It's best practice to not handle GUIs on the Server. Instead, you can communicate to LocalScripts what they need to show using RemoteFunctions/RemoteEvents.